# what is presentational component or container component in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux. I tried above question on searching google even on stackoverflow. But can't find suitable answer for me. I want to know

> What is presentation and container component in redux?

and

> what is smart and dump component in react?

with the suitable example, which will help me to understand above, Thanks.

Comment: *I tried above question on searching google even on stackoverflow* - no wonder. There's no such thing as 'component in redux'. Redux doesn't deal with components. React does.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot to write react instead of redux.

Answer (score 1):

> What is presentation and container component in redux?

A presentation component is the one which is responsible for rendering something on the view.

A Container component is something that is connected to the redux store. Typically `connect` from react redux is used to connect to the store

> what is smart and dump component in redux?

A smart component is something that has some logic within it that is uses to render the view or process data like fetching data, maintain state, handling user interactions

A Dumb component is usually a ccomponent that just takes in the props and renders the view without actually handling any user interactions itself

For example

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state =  { 
      count: 0
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
             <User data={this.props.user} />
             <div>{this.state.count}</div>
             <button onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count + 1}))}>Increment</button>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

const User = ({ data }) => (
   <div>
      <div>{data.id}</div>
      <div>{data.name}</div>
      <div>{data.surname}</div>
   </div>
)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
      user: state.user
   }
}
const ContainerApp =  connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
```

In the above example `App` in itself is a presentation component along with a smart component as it handles user interaction of incrementing and showing count. However `ContainerApp` is a component that is connected to redux store making use of presentational App component and is thus a container. `User` component on the other hand is a dumb component along with a presentational component since it just takes some props and renders view based on it

Comment: please edit your answer. As i can't understand what is "A contains component".

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I updated my answer

Comment: Is above example for container or presentational component?

Comment: Please check the description below the example. It explains what exactly each component is